# Loop with enclosing items every 'n' steps

Tags: php

I'm listing elements with a `foreach`, and I would like to enclose items in something tag `n` by `n`:

```
$i = 0;
$open = $done = TRUE;
$n = 3;
$opening = "<div>";
$closing = "</div>";
$names = array("Doc", "Marty", "George", "Lorraine", "Einstein", "Biff"); 

foreach($names as $name) { /** $condition was not a bool. My fault. */

    if($open && !($i % n)) {
        print $opening;
        $open = FALSE;
        $done = !$open;
    } elseif(!($i % n)) $done = FALSE;

    /** print element. */
    print $name;

    if(!$open && !($i % n) && !$done) {
        print $closing;
        $open = TRUE;
        $done = !$open;
    }

    $i++;

}
```

Do you think this snippet can be improved? It would be better to have fewer check variables such as `$open` or `$done`.

Comment: @albert can you also add what n and the condition is suppose to represent? Does it get it's value from another part of the code?

Comment: Can you provide as working example ? (Without parser errors). From its current state i pretty much have no clue that code is supposed to be doing (or at least it's nothing i think i can improve apon in a meaningfull way) . i, open and done are php variables ? ($ sign ?)

Comment: I am very sorry. I updated the question.

Comment: `} elseif(!(i % n)) done = FALSE;` is not PHP!, `}elseif(!($i % $n)) $done = FALSE;` is, this is a job for StackOverflow before you it can be improved

Comment: open and close still me the $ signs, saidly i can't edit it myself (and i don't want to put in a question just for that.) Thanks for the edit ! Much clearer now.

Comment: Could you provide more explanation about what this method is meant to do? It might help people trying to improve it.. Are $i and $n magic numbers?

Comment: @Alberteddu, Please only submit working code for review. Your code is not going to run because you miss some $'s at the start of some variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One problem with your solution is that it won't print the last closing `</div>` tag if there are less than `$n` elements inside the last `<div>`.

An approach which fixes that problem and also simplifies the conditional logic for deciding when to print the tags is to chunk the array first using `array_chunk` and then iterate over the chunks. Now we only need one boolean variable to remember which chunks to surround in tags.

```
function alternate($names, $n, $opening, $closing) {
    $tag = TRUE;
    foreach(array_chunk($names, $n) as $chunk) {
        if($tag) {
            print $opening;
        }
        foreach($chunk as $name) {
            print $name;
        }
        if($tag) {
            print $closing;
        }
        $tag = !$tag;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternate solution without the overhead of the array_chunk call. (Don't get me wrong, I love array_chunk and use it for a lot of things, but this isn't one where it's needed.)

```
$array = getData(...);
$n = 5; //or whatever you want to chunk into
echo "<div>"; //always open one
$lcv = 1; // loop count variable
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    //format $key/$val as needed here...
    if ($lcv++ % $n == 0) { //every Nth item
        echo "</div><div>"; //close old one and open new one
    }
}
echo "</div>"; //always close the last one.
```

Worst case here is you might have an empty `<div></div>` block at the end if you had an exact multiple of n.... but that's not really that big a deal 99.999% of the time. :) If it is... then you can catch it like so:

```
$array = getData(...);
$num = count($array);
$n = 5; //or whatever you want to chunk into
echo "<div>"; //always open one
$lcv = 1; // loop count variable
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    //format $key/$val as needed here...
    if ($lcv++ % $n == 0 && $lcv < $num) { // every Nth item, unless we're done
        echo "</div><div>"; //close old one and open new one
    }
}
echo "</div>"; //always close the last one.
```

(Of course you can use `print`, `echo`, or `?>...<?` tags... whatever you want to actually do all the output, doesn't matter.)

And to be honest, I'd probably add one more case to it:

```
$array = getData(...);
$num = count($array);
if ($num == 0) {
    echo "<div>No results?</div>";
} else {
    $n = 5; //or whatever you want to chunk into
    echo "<div>"; //always open one
    $lcv = 1; // loop count variable
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        //format $key/$val as needed here...
        if ($lcv++ % $n == 0 && $lcv < $num) { // every Nth item, unless we're done
            echo "</div><div>"; //close old one and open new one
        }
    }
    echo "</div>"; //always close the last one.
}
```

Just to cover the case that whatever search it is didn't actually return anything.